# Create regular expression using the rex command in Splunk to return xml child elements

Tags: regex, xml, splunk

I am trying to use the Splunk command **rex** which uses regular expressions to extract data from a log statement.  This is the part of the xml of interest:

```
<tmsTrip xmlns="removed_for_security" xmlns:ns2="removed_for_security">
   <recordType>PURCHASEDLINEHAUL</recordType>
   <eventType>DISPATCH</eventType>
   <updatedDateGMT>2020-05-21T17:22:55.000Z</updatedDateGMT>
   <origin>
      <ns2:numberCode>923</ns2:numberCode>
      <ns2:numberType>2</ns2:numberType>
   </origin>
   <destination>
      <ns2:numberCode>72</ns2:numberCode>
      <ns2:numberType>2</ns2:numberType>
   </destination>
```

I need the **numberCode** from the origin and destination.
This rex returns the first one, 923.

```
rex field=_raw "\<ns2\:numberCode\>(?P<origin>[^\<]+)"
```

I need a rex to return the second one, 72.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell `rex` to return both of them using the `max_match` option.

```
| rex max_match=0 "\<ns2\:numberCode\>(?P<origin>[^\<]+)"
| eval originCode = mvindex(origin, 0), destCode = mvindex(origin, 1)
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to know the order of the matches so this fails if destination precedes origin in the XML.

You should be able to use `spath` to extract the entire XML and refer to "origin.numberCode" and "destination.numberCode", but I don't have enough experience with that command to offer much guidance.

Comment: WOW! Thank worked like a charm! I tried using **spath** and **xpath**. I think the configuration is not set for them and I can't change it.  But your works beautifully!!! THANKS AGAIN!